# Estimated means for groups based on continous predictor in GAMM

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, lsmeans

I have fitted a GAMM using the mgcv package in R. The predictor age is a continous variable and is included with a smooth function in the model.

```
library(mgcv)
themodel <- gam(survival ~ s(age, bs="tp", k = 4) + 
                s(mother_id, bs="re") + s(litter_id, bs="re"),
              family=binomial, data=thedata, method = "ML")
```

I want to have model-based estimates for the reponse for three age groups, i.e. one year old, from two to five years, and six years and older. What is the best approach to do this?

In the rest of the paper, we present estimated marginal means using the emmeans package but I am not sure how to do this for groups based on a continous predictor. Any tips that can help me in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: I think {emmeans} calls this `emtrends()` because the effect size is the estimated trend (slope) at the requested covariate values. For a GAM, you have the additional complication that that trend (slope) is potentially different for all values of `x` (`age` in your case). It seems to me that you will have to think about how you want to define "one year old" (is it a point estimate of the slope (derivative of smooth) at `age == 1`? Then what about the same thing for "two-five years"? Do you pick `age = 3.5` (the mid point) or average over multiple `age`?

Comment: Or you could just compute the derivative of the smooth (or the response, after excluding the random effects) for many values, evenly spread over the range of `age` of interest. If you can provide more guidance on what you want to do, and possibly a reproducible example, I will expand these comments to an answer.

Comment: Thanks! I have made a simple example to illustrate the question here: https://github.com/knutanders/gam_example/